# Error during build of sample Next.js app

Tags: jss, nextjs

After creating a JSS Next.js app, I'd like to build it with `jss build` command and deploy, but that gives me GraphQL related error:

```
./src/components/graphql/GraphQL-ConnectedDemo.dynamic.tsx:114:72
Type error: Argument of type 'TypedDocumentNode<ConnectedDemoQueryQuery, Exact<{ datasource: string; contextItem: string; language: string; }>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | DocumentNode'.
  Type 'TypedDocumentNode<ConnectedDemoQueryQuery, Exact<{ datasource: string; contextItem: string; language: string; }>>' is not assignable to type 'DocumentNode'.
    Types of property 'kind' are incompatible.
      Type '"Document"' is not assignable to type 'Kind.DOCUMENT'.
```

Commands that I ran:

```
npm install @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@20.0.1 -g
npx create-sitecore-jss@20.0.1 nextjs
```

Selected *REST* for fetching Layout and Dictionary data and *SSG* to be used for prerendering.

If I remove GraphQL demo components, then a different error is returned by `jss build`:

```
./src/pages/_app.tsx:21:11
Type error: Property 'dictionary' does not exist on type '{}'.

  19 |
  20 | function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps): JSX.Element {
> 21 |   const { dictionary, ...rest } = pageProps;
```

I'm fairly new to headless development with Next.js, so would appreciate any pointers to how to get sample application built and deployed.

Comment: Same issue, I tried with "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs": "^20.0.1" and it works fine. However with "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs": "^21.0.0". I'm facing same issue. I don´t know if this is version related. If someone else found the solution please post it.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have a fix for this issue I do have a workaround.

I've turned off Typescript and ESLint for builds to get the sample site building.

Create two new files

1. `src\lib\next-config\plugins\typescript.js`

```
const typescript = (nextConfig = {}) => {
  return Object.assign({}, nextConfig, {
    typescript: {
      ignoreBuildErrors: true,
    },
  });
};

module.exports = typescript;
```

2. `src\lib\next-config\plugins\eslint.js`

```
const eslint = (nextConfig = {}) => {
  return Object.assign({}, nextConfig, {
    eslint: {
      ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
  });
};

module.exports = eslint;
```

This should allow `jss build` to work although I was testing with `yarn build`